# Combine dictionaries in a list based on two values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.8

Am looking to combine dictionaries in list of dictionaries.
My list of dicts looks like this:

```
opt = [{'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 138.5, 'p_bid': 0.4375, 'p_ask': 0.46875}, 
       {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 0.6875, 'p_ask': 0.71875}, 
       {'expiry': '2020-07-22', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 1.015625, 'p_ask': 1.0625}, 
       {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 138.5, 'c_bid': 0.6875, 'c_ask': 0.734375}, 
       {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 139.0, 'c_bid': 0.4375, 'c_ask': 0.484375}, 
       {'expiry': '2020-07-22', 'strike': 139.0, 'c_bid': 0.28125, 'c_ask': 0.3125}]
```

The dictionaries need to be combined pairwise where 'expiry' and 'strike' are identical.
the desired output looks like this:

```
[{'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 138.5, 'p_bid': 0.4375, 'p_ask': 0.46875, 'c_bid': 0.6875, 'c_ask': 0.734375}, 
 {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 0.6875, 'p_ask': 0.71875, 'c_bid': 0.4375, 'c_ask': 0.484375}, 
 {'expiry': '2020-07-22', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 1.015625, 'p_ask': 1.0625, 'c_bid': 0.28125, 'c_ask': 0.3125}}]
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this and where did it go wrong?

Comment: am sorry. can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. found answers how to do something similar when only one key needs to be identical. Been experimenting with `defaultdict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The "Naive" approach:

Add the dicts to a new result list. For each new dict check if it matches with a dict already in the list. If it does, merge them. If not, add it to the list:

```py
res = [opt[0]]
for d_new in opt[1:]:
    for d in res:
        if d['expiry'] == d_new['expiry'] and d['strike'] == d_new['strike']:
       #if (d['expiry'], d['strike']) == (d_new['expiry'], d_new['strike']):
            d.update(d_new)
            break
    else:
        res.append(d_new)
```

This uses the [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct which is useful here because we want to add a new dict to the list only if it didn't match with any other in the result list. If we found a match we merge them and `break` and the `else` will not be executed.

## A slight improvement:

The above approach results a time complexity of `O(n^2)` for looping all dicts for each dict (not exactly, but academicly this is still `O(n^2)`). To try and improve that, a second approach can be to group together the dicts with similar `expiry` and `strike` at one go (`O(n)`):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

merged_dicts = defaultdict(dict)
for d in opt:
    merged_dicts[(d['expiry'], d['strike'])].update(d)

res = list(merged_dicts.values())
```

This uses the [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to easily merge the dicts without too many `if` conditions. We also use `dict`'s [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method to actually merge them.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly easy way to do that is to use pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(opt)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["expiry", "strike"])
[ v.dropna().to_dict() for k,v in df.iterrows() ]
```

Results in :

```
[{'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 138.5, 'p_bid': 0.4375, 'p_ask': 0.46875},
 {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 0.6875, 'p_ask': 0.71875},
 {'expiry': '2020-07-22', 'strike': 139.0, 'p_bid': 1.015625, 'p_ask': 1.0625}]
```

Note that when dropping duplicates, I'm keeping the first element. One could easily leave the last element if that what you want, but using:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["expiry", "strike"], keep="last")
```

In this case, the result is:

```
[{'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 138.5, 'c_bid': 0.6875, 'c_ask': 0.734375},
 {'expiry': '2020-06-26', 'strike': 139.0, 'c_bid': 0.4375, 'c_ask': 0.484375},
 {'expiry': '2020-07-22', 'strike': 139.0, 'c_bid': 0.28125, 'c_ask': 0.3125}]
```

And another way is to use a dictionary to reduce 'similar' values:

```
reduction_dict = {(x["expiry"], x["strike"]):x for x in opt }
list(reduction_dict.values())
```

Comment: the 2nd solution gives the desired output while the pandas solution results in `nan` values for `c_bid` and `c_ask`.

Comment: @steff - correct. I updated the pandas solution to take care of nan values.

Comment: the pandas solution still doesn't give the desired output. But I like your second way. Think Pandas would require `groupby` and `apply`.